# Multiple linear regression with gradient descent

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, gradient-descent

Halo,

I'm new in machine learning and Python and I want to predict the [Kaggle House Sales in King County dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction) with my **gradient descent**.

I'm splitting 70% (15k rows) training and 30% (6k rows) testing and I choose 5 features from 19, but there is a performance issue, the algorithm took so much time (more than 11 hours), 100% memory and failed to execute.

This is my Gradient Descent class:

```
class GradientDescent:

    X_train = []
    Y_train = []
    X_test  = []
    Y_test  = []
    lr = 0
    max_iter = 0
    theta = 0

    def __init__(self, X_train,Y_train,X_test,Y_test, lr=0.01, max_iter=100):
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.Y_train = Y_train
        self.X_test  = X_test
        self.Y_test  = Y_test
        self.lr = lr
        self.max_iter = max_iter
        self.theta = np.random.randn(X_train.shape[1], 1)
        print(self.theta)

    def costFunction(self,theta,X,y):
        "1/2m * E(h0-y)**2"
        m = len(y)
        y_pred = X.dot(theta)
        cost = (1/2*m) * np.sum(np.square(y_pred-y))

        return cost


    def estimate(self):
        m = len(self.Y_train)

        mse_hist = np.zeros(self.max_iter)

        #theta_hist = np.zeros(max_iter)
        i = 0
        while i < self.max_iter or mse_hist[i] > 0.01:
            y_pred = np.dot(self.X_train,self.theta)

            error = y_pred-self.Y_train
            self.theta = self.theta - (1/m)*self.lr*(self.X_train.T.dot((error)))
            mse_hist[i] = self.costFunction(self.theta,self.X_train, self.Y_train)

            #print(mse_hist[i])
            i+=1            
        return (self.theta, mse_hist)


    def test(self):
        res = pd.DataFrame()
        for i,row in self.X_test.iterrows():
            price_pred = np.dot(row.values,self.theta)
            res = row
            res['price_actual'] = self.Y_test[i]
            res['price_predict'] = price_pred

        res['r2_score'] = r2_score(res['price_actual'].values, res['price_predict'])
        res.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Any advice to make it better?

Answer (score 1):

In general the code seems fine though I haven't tested it. The only error I could find was that you may not be incrementing `i` in your while loop so the loop is never exiting.

Comment: oh, i forgot to add it in my question but in my code the increment is available

Comment: The class itself seems fine and 15k rows is pretty reasonable that a decent computer shouldn't be using 100% memory or running for multiple hours with 100 iterations. May be there is something happening in the code that is calling this class. 

As an aside, as training becomes expensive due to larger number of rows or features, Stochastic Gradient Descent starts becoming a more computationally efficient solution, so you could look into that as well.

Comment: problem solved, GD is good for small dataset, and i've tried with mini batch GD , it's faster and good enough for learning purpose

Comment: How did you solve the problem, did mini batch GD help?

Comment: yes i dont know i'm guessing the problem with original GD is my matrix calculation for finding theta, 15000 rows multiplication at same time make memory exhausted  so with mini batch we just calculate with batch size